# Tag ordering bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sorting

When you search through the recently created tags, [ordering by the newest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), if you type something into the search box and then delete it, the tags are then shown alphabetically ordered.  I would expect to see the tags again ordered by the creation date.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1 [Click here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) (noting that the link orders by 'newest')  You should see:

[image: Tags ordered by creation date]

2 Enter 'waffles' into the search box.  You should see:

[image: Waffles. Yum.]

3 Erase 'waffles' from the search box and you should see:

[image: No more waffles. Boo.]

The list of tags is now ordered alphabetically, but you had requested that they be ordered by creation date.  Please consider this an ultra-low priority bug (or status-by-design).

Comment: This was fixed a while back.